# Can't get the length of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to get the length of a list created by a function. I am getting this error and I don't understand what it means:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `t1 -> a0' with actual type `Int'
    * The function `length' is applied to two value arguments,
        but its type `(Int -> [String]) -> Int' has only one
      In the first argument of `print', namely `(length strings 1)'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (length strings 1)
  |
9 |     print(length strings 1)
  |           ^^
```

Calling the function by using print (strings 1) works so I don't understand why I can't get the length of it.

```
strings :: Int -> [ String ]
strings 0 = [""] 
strings n = concat ( map (\x -> map (\ tail -> x: tail ) tails ) ['a'.. 'z'])
    where tails = strings (n -1)

main :: Int main = do
    print(length strings 1)
```

Comment: run `print(length $ strings 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length strings 1` means you apply the function `length` to the arguments `strings` and `1`. In other languages that would be written `length(strings, 1)`. But `1` is supposed to be the argument to `strings` instead, so you should write one of the following instead:

```
print (length (strings 1))
print (length $ strings 1)
print $ length $ strings 1
print . length $ strings 1    -- recommended version
(print . length . strings) 1
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to convey to the reader, you may also want `print . length . strings $ 1` (or variants). The desiderata for me is: which makes more sense as a mental chunk, `print . length . strings` or `strings 1`? An especially common example where I want the fewer-dots version is `foo . bar . baz $ zip x y` rather than `foo . bar . baz . zip x $ y`; in most other cases, I prefer more dots.